# Are there any geniuses in the Marvel Universe who are not superheroes?

Tags: marvel, super-hero

It seems that every genius in the Marvel Universe undergoes some sort of horrible accident and becomes a superhero, or, is born a mutant/creates his own superpowers. Mr. Fantastic, Beast, Tony Stark, Bruce Banner, Hank Pym, et cetera: All are the top geniuses/scientists on earth. Peter Parker was brilliant enough, as a teenager, to invent web-shooters. (A fortunate coincidence that he was also bitten by radioactive spider, rather than, say, a rhinoceros.)

So: Are there any geniuses mentioned in the Marvel Universe that don't have superpowers? Just a normal, run-of-the-mill, super genius. Doesn't fight crime, just publishes papers, teaches classes, and so on.

Comment: When they are identified they inevitably get invited into some completely safe excursion/experiment/demonstration...  and end up a superhero/villan... its the laws of comic books.

Comment: You want a comic book that details the life and times of your average, run-of-the-mill genius that works to cure cancer or works at the LHC? Don't they call those scientific journals?

Comment: Not all are fortunate like Batman..

Comment: Let's face it, the comic was called the X-men, not the N-Men (normal scientists, hated and feared by the world that couldn't understand them). Hmmm. Now that I think about that, maybe there COULD be a comic about under-appreciated super-geniuses on the run from a world they helped to create...

Comment: It's not that fortunate a coincidence; the average New York teenager encounters more spiders than rhinoceri.

Comment: I have a feeling if other geniuses are inventing flying suits and giving themselves superpowers it ups the stakes a little. Do you honestly think distinguished professors like Dr. Otto Octavius or Dr. Kurt Conner would have experimented on themselves if people like Tony Stark and Reed Richards hadn't given them massive inferiority complexes?

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr Isn't something like that part of Dr. Doom's backstory? Like, he blames Reed Richards for messing up one of his experiments or something.

Comment: If YOU had the ability and resources to give yourself super-powers, would you stay normal?

Comment: I can't recall any in the Marvel comics, but I might start looking for any Marvel Counterparts to Lucius Fox -- I suppose that might include pepper potts, but I'm only familiar with her as portrayed by Gwyneth Paltrow, and aside from acute business acumen she doesn't really portray any STEM proclivities.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Moira MacTaggert](http://marvel.wikia.com/Moira_Kinross_%28Earth-616%29) works in the study of Mutants and is considered a world renowned scientist.

[Dr. Kavita Rao](http://marvel.wikia.com/Kavita_Rao_%28Earth-616%29), a world renowned geneticist, eventually joined X-Club, and was brought into a sinister plot by Ord while promoting her discovery of the cure to being a mutant.

Answer (score 4):

Uhhmm... Tony Stark, kind of. I mean, he doesn't have superpowers, strictly speaking... but he does all that fighting crime stuff.

I'd include Kingpin in that list. Criminal genius, and all.

If it were DC, I'd include Lex Luthor.

Comment: You'd call Kingpin a "super*hero*"?

Comment: I'd call Kingpin a "genius in the Marvel universe who is NOT a superhero" and doesn't have superpowers as the question asked.